# Prism 4 + Mef + public partial class App = Bag?

Tags: c#, mef, prism-4

I'm trying to implement the interface IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification but unfortunately it does not work.
This bug I have only the prism. I can't understand why this is happening.

[Test Application](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=4e1f0617c9aaf89e&permissionsChanged=1&id=4E1F0617C9AAF89E!120#)

```
public partial class App : Application, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [Import]
    public IPlugin plugin { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied() // This code is not called
    {
        var x = plugin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running in release mode? Can it be possible that the compiler ignores any call to OnImportSatisfied since there is no logic inside?

Comment: No I am working in debug mode. I added method to plugin.TestMetod();. But unfortunately that does not work.